# unable to get ngRoute to work with my meanstack app

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I noticed this is a popular question being asked, and i have looked at all of the previous questions and none of them seem to help me with my problem to my knowledge.

I am unable to get the page to load the about page under partials when i visit the URL localhost:3000/about.

this is the message io get when i try and visit localhost:3000/about:
Cannot GET /about

my folder structure is this:

[image]

Here is my app.js file:

```
/*global angular:true */
angular.module('myApp', [
  'AppCtrl',
  'ngRoute'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/", {templateUrl: "index.html"}).
    when("/about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html"});
}]);
```

and here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>New Meanstack APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>MeanStack App</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.name"></input>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.email"></input>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.number"></input>
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addContact()">Add Contact</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update()">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(contact._id)">Remove</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit(contact._id)">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Where is your ng-view?

Comment: i removed that section of it so not to clutter.

Comment: the ng-view is directly under the .container div

Comment: Ah okay, that's where I'd expect it to be. Did you try accessing your side via localhost:3000/#/about ?

Comment: it just takes me to the main page index.html

Comment: Are you able to GET the about.html when you directly access it? localhost:3000/partials/about.html

Comment: I am able to access it directly

Answer (score 0):

Edited: 
Your not making use of ng-view, the route provider is looking to render the views in ng-view. If you need help I have a mini MEAN stack setup. https://github.com/Kalevera/q

The angular code is located in public/js 
The view templates are in public/u
PLEASE NOTE the login is simply to show how to transfer data and complete angular routing. The login is not up to Oauth standards (that I know of, haven't verified)